# AutoMapper map multiple models and ignore non-existing properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map multiple domain models to one view model. I found [this](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2010/12/22/automapper-mapping-from-multiple-objects.aspx) link which is able to do just that. However, I have several domain model properties that do not exist in the view model. When I try to map the models, I am getting the error:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

This is because I am not ignoring the other properties. All the answers I've seen mention using option.Ignore() on the Mapper.CreateMap function. However, in the link I provided, the Mapper.CreateMap function is not used. The only call to AutoMapper is:

```
    Mapper.Map(source, destination, sourceType, destinationType);
```

How can I do the ignore in this case? Or is there a better way to do both mapping multiple models and ignoring properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a `Mapper.CreateMap` in your `Application_Start` for **all** the objects you are dealing with:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceDomain1, MyViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceDomain2, MyViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceDomain3, MyViewModel>();
```

The fact that you have properties in your domain models which are not present in your view model is not a problem at all. They won't be taken into account. On the other hand you could use the `.Ignore()` method when configuring your AutoMapper to indicate that some property present in both the source and the target should be ignored.

Comment: Got it! I thought there was no need for that if I use the EntityMapper class in the link. Thank you very much!

Comment: The `EntityMapper` class in the link is just a wrapper around AutoMapper. It doesn't replace nor override its fundamental concepts.